# Java 11 junit jupiter assertThrows

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy

I try to migrate from Java 8 to 11 and get an error in my test class that I don't understand.

My failing (groovy) test is:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
class TestSpringBeanScopeChecker {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx

    @Test
    void testSingletonFail() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class) {
            SpringBeanScopeChecker.check(ctx, DummyPrototype.class, BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
        }
    }
}
```

The SpringBeanScopeChecker:

```
public class SpringBeanScopeChecker {

    private SpringBeanScopeChecker() {}

    public static void check(ApplicationContext ctx, Class<?> type, String scope)
            throws IllegalStateException {

        AbstractApplicationContext actx = (ctx instanceof AbstractApplicationContext) ? 
                ((AbstractApplicationContext) ctx) : 
                new StaticApplicationContext(ctx);

        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory = actx.getBeanFactory();

        for (String key : ctx.getBeanNamesForType(type)) {
            BeanDefinition definition = factory.getMergedBeanDefinition(key);

            if (!scope.equals(definition.getScope())) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Every spring bean "
                                + "must be request scoped in the bean configuration. The current scope is: "
                                + definition.getScope());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for the test I'm expecting a `IllegalArgumentException`. And this is working fine with `Java8`.
When I switch to `Java11` and execute the test I get this error:

```
[ERROR] testSingletonFail  Time elapsed: 0.009 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown
==> expected: <java.lang.IllegalStateException> but was: <java.lang.AbstractMethodError>
         at TestSpringBeanScopeChecker.testSingletonFail(TestSpringBeanScopeChecker.groovy:22)
 Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class
 TestSpringBeanScopeChecker does not define or inherit an
 implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object
 getProperty(java.lang.String)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
         at TestSpringBeanScopeChecker.testSingletonFail(TestSpringBeanScopeChecker.groovy:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has the same problem I write down the solution for this.
The problem was misconfiguration of the `groovy-eclipse-compiler` and `groovy-eclipse-batch`.

My groovy version is managed by spring-boot and I didn't update the groovy-eclipse-batch according to the `groovy.version` from the spring-boot pom.

According to this issue on [github](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/1078):

You have to compile with `groovy-eclipse-batch` and `groovy runtime` in the same version. `groovy-eclipse-batch` and `groovy runtime` should be matched up. E.g. `batch 2.5.10-0x` and `runtime 2.5.10` or `batch 3.0.1-0x` and `runtime 3.0.1`.